# Logic of if ifelse and elseif in php

Tags: php, post

I am comparing seven (7) boolean values 1 (true) or 0 (false) of a primary set and five (5) of a secondary set with an addition of 2 n/a choices. If all 12 come back as true, then the $class is set to Reuse. If the primary set is True and Secondary is false then it comes back as Resale. If any of the primary set comes back False, it's set to Repair. This is what I have so far, and don't get back any syntax errors, but the "class" is coming back incorrect.

```html
<?php
$primary = false;
$class = null;

if ($_POST['poweradapter'] == "1"
    && $_POST['mobocpu'] == "1"
    && $_POST['memory'] == "1"
    && $_POST['harddrive'] == "1"
    && $_POST['screen'] == "1"
    && $_POST['battery'] == "1"
    && $_POST['hinge'] == "1")
{
    $class = "Reuse";
    $primary = true;
}
else
{
    $class = "Repair or Recycle";
}

if ($primary
    && in_array($_POST['opticaldrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && in_array($_POST['floppydrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && $_POST['usb'] == "1"
    && $_POST['trackpad'] == "1"
    && $_POST['keyboard'] == "1")
{
    /*
     * "secondary" is implicit here, but we never did anything with the 
     * $secondary variable in the original script
     */
    $class = "Reuse";
}
else
{
    $class = ($primary) ? "Reuse" : "Repair or Recycle";
}
?>
```

Final working script

```html
<?php
$primary = false;
$class = null;


if ($_POST['poweradapter'] == "1"
    && $_POST['mobocpu'] == "1"
    && $_POST['memory'] == "1"
    && $_POST['harddrive'] == "1"
    && $_POST['screen'] == "1"
    && $_POST['battery'] == "1"
    && $_POST['hinge'] == "1")
{
    $primary = true;
 $class = "Resale";
}
else
{
    $class = "Repair or Recycle";
}
if ($primary && in_array($_POST['opticaldrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && in_array($_POST['floppydrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && $_POST['usb'] == "1"
    && $_POST['trackpad'] == "1"
    && $_POST['keyboard'] == "1")
{
 $class = "Reuse";
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean the `class` is coming back as incorrect? Are you getting an error? Or simply no output?

Comment: You are not explicitly checking for repair condition, where if $primary=False, set $class = repair

Comment: Can you also check if post parameters are coming as desired, can you print  them and check, whether they contain the exact values?

Comment: Yes they are exact 0,1,or 2

Comment: There is an issue with second if statement with  or , try using this - if (($_POST['opticaldrive']=="1" || $_POST['opticaldrive']== "2") && ($_POST['floppydrive']=="1" || $_POST['floppydrive']=="2") && $_POST['usb']=="1" && $_POST['trackpad']=="1" && $_POST['keyboard']=="1") - i have updated the same in my answer as well

Comment: You should be using boolean values (`true` and `false`), not strings like `"True"` and `"False"`. That's just another way for your code to break on a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.. That was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using double equals in the body of the first if statement.

```
$class == "Reuse";
$primary == "True";
```

should be

```
$class = "Reuse";
$primary = "True";
```

There are a lot of things you could do to make this more readable and maintainable, but the bug is the equality vs assignment issue.

Here is what I would do to make this easier to work with:

```
<?php
$primary = false;
$class = null;

if ($_POST['poweradapter'] == "1"
    && $_POST['mobocpu'] == "1"
    && $_POST['memory'] == "1"
    && $_POST['harddrive'] == "1"
    && $_POST['screen'] == "1"
    && $_POST['battery'] == "1"
    && $_POST['hinge'] == "1")
{
    $class = "Reuse";
    $primary = true;
}
else
{
    $class = "Repair or Recycle";
}

if ($primary
    && in_array($_POST['opticaldrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && in_array($_POST['floppydrive'], ["1", "2"])
    && $_POST['usb'] == "1"
    && $_POST['trackpad'] == "1"
    && $_POST['keyboard'] == "1")
{
    /*
     * "secondary" is implicit here, but we never did anything with the 
     * $secondary variable in the original script
     */
    $class = "Reuse";
}
else
{
    $class = ($primary) ? "Resale" : "Repair or Recycle";
}
```

Hope this helps.

[Edit]
Since you're still having trouble with the logic itself, this is an ideal case for unit testing. Here's a little script you can run from the command line to test and fine tune your logic without having to worry about getting [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) set up:

```
<?php
class MyService
{
    public static $CLASS_REUSE = 'Reuse';
    public static $CLASS_RESALE = 'Resale';
    public static $CLASS_REPAIR_RECYCLE = 'Repair or Recycle';

    public static function determineClassForInputParameters($params)
    {
        $primary = false;
        $class = null;

        if ($params['poweradapter'] == "1"
            && $params['mobocpu'] == "1"
            && $params['memory'] == "1"
            && $params['harddrive'] == "1"
            && $params['screen'] == "1"
            && $params['battery'] == "1"
            && $params['hinge'] == "1")
        {
            $primary = true;
        }

        if ($primary
            && in_array($params['opticaldrive'], ["1", "2"])
            && in_array($params['floppydrive'], ["1", "2"])
            && $params['usb'] == "1"
            && $params['trackpad'] == "1"
            && $params['keyboard'] == "1")
        {
            $class = self::$CLASS_REUSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $class = ($primary) ? self::$CLASS_RESALE : self::$CLASS_REPAIR_RECYCLE;
        }

        return $class;
    }
}

class MyServiceTest
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
        assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);
        assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);
        assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, array($this, 'assertHandler'));
    }

    public function determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnReuse()
    {
        $params = [
            'poweradapter' => 1,
            'mobocpu' => 1,
            'memory' => 1,
            'harddrive' => 1,
            'screen' => 1,
            'battery' => 1,
            'hinge' => 1,
            'opticaldrive' => 1,
            'floppydrive' => 1,
            'usb' => 1,
            'trackpad' => 1,
            'keyboard' => 1
        ];

        $class = MyService::determineClassForInputParameters($params);

        if (assert($class == MyService::$CLASS_REUSE, 'Expected class ' . MyService::$CLASS_REUSE . ', found ' . $class))
        {
            echo "determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnReuse Passed\n";
        }
    }

    public function determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnResale()
    {
        $params = [
            'poweradapter' => 1,
            'mobocpu' => 1,
            'memory' => 1,
            'harddrive' => 1,
            'screen' => 1,
            'battery' => 1,
            'hinge' => 1,
            'opticaldrive' => 1,
            'floppydrive' => 1,
            'usb' => 1,
            'trackpad' => 1,
            'keyboard' => 0
        ];

        $class = MyService::determineClassForInputParameters($params);

        if (assert($class == MyService::$CLASS_RESALE, 'Expected class ' . MyService::$CLASS_RESALE . ', found ' . $class))
        {
            echo "determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnResale Passed\n";
        }
    }

    public function determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnRePairOrRecycle()
    {
        $params = [
            'poweradapter' => 0,
            'mobocpu' => 1,
            'memory' => 1,
            'harddrive' => 1,
            'screen' => 1,
            'battery' => 1,
            'hinge' => 1,
            'opticaldrive' => 1,
            'floppydrive' => 1,
            'usb' => 1,
            'trackpad' => 1,
            'keyboard' => 1
        ];

        $class = MyService::determineClassForInputParameters($params);

        if (assert($class == MyService::$CLASS_REPAIR_RECYCLE, 'Expected class ' . MyService::$CLASS_REPAIR_RECYCLE . ', found ' . $class))
        {
            echo "determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnRePairOrRecycle Passed\n";
        }
    }

    public function assertHandler($file, $line, $code, $desc = null)
    {
        echo "Assertion failed at $file:$line: $code";
        if ($desc)
        {
            echo ": $desc";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}

$tester = new MyServiceTest();

$tester->determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnReuse();
$tester->determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnResale();
$tester->determineClassForInputParametersShouldReturnRePairOrRecycle();
```

You may find it useful to adopt some of the techniques shown in the test, like encapsulating your logic in a service class to make it easier to test and use in multiple places, using static variables for your "class" names to prevent typo errors, etc. Or you can just tune your logic with this and copy it into your existing code.

It may seem like a lot of overhead, but the few minutes it takes to set up tests for your logic far outweighs the hours you can waste trying to figure it out by submitting requests through your front end.

Comment: Well then.. I thought about dropping it line by line, but as far as getting the code readable In logic I  thought keeping it line by line.. I will try this next. And thank you about the double equals though not that it mattered since my logic was screwed up

Comment: Almost got it with this method, the second set is not putting out Repair or Recycle on fail (false)

Answer (score 0):

Here try to first set primary and secondary flag to true or false, then compare for the conditions, below is the code snippet, hope this helps.

There are two problems
1. in the first if you are setting $primary as $primary == "True" instead of $primary="True" , so here instead of setting the primary flag, it is comparing whether $primary is true. same is the case with $class.

2. in the second if statement -$_POST['floppydrive']=="1" or"2" is always true , so it results in true block of if getting executed every time, here or "2", can be changed to  - ($_POST['floppydrive']=="1" || $_POST['floppydrive']=="2")

This should get you desired result

```html
  

  
    
<?php

//setting primary flag
if ($_POST['poweradapter']=="1" && $_POST['mobocpu']=="1" && $_POST['memory']=="1" && $_POST['harddrive']=="1" && $_POST['screen']=="1" && $_POST['battery']=="1" && $_POST['hinge']=="1"){
 $primary = "True";
}else{
 $primary = "False";
}

//setting secondary flag
if (($_POST['opticaldrive']=="1" || $_POST['opticaldrive']== "2") && ($_POST['floppydrive']=="1" || $_POST['floppydrive']== "2") && $_POST['usb']=="1" && $_POST['trackpad']=="1" && $_POST['keyboard']=="1"){
 $secondary = "True";
}else{
 $primary = "False";
}


//setting the class now
if ($primary == "True" && $secondary=="True") {
 $class = "Reuse";
}
elseif ($primary == "True" && $secondary=="False") {
 $class = "Resale";
}
else{
 $class = "Repair or Recycle";
}
?>
```

output
Power Adapter: 1 
Motherboard: 1 
Memory: 1 
Hard/SSD Drive: 1 
Screen: 1 
Battery: 0 
Screen Hinge: 0 
USB Ports: 0 
Track/Touch Pad: 0 
Keyboard: 0 
Optical Drive: 0 
Floppy Drive: 1 
was added with an Class of Repair or Recycle